# Bulk replacing content of multiple pages/posts?

Tags: posts, pages, bulk

I have multiple pages, and some of their contents are same while others are different. Is it possible to replace the content of all of these pages with same content at once? I have thought of two methods which could be possible and are listed below. But is there any better approach?

1. Write a MySQL query which updates contents in a range of post IDs
2. Update one of them and use post duplicating plugin (this isn't very good solution in this case, because all of these pages have some unique meta values)

UPDATE: Wrote a MySQL UPDATE query, but still wondering if there's a better method.

Answer (score 0):

The sql command would be the most effective, clean and fast method to my knowledge.

You can use this command to set all content to the desired value:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = 'YOUR POST CONTENT HERE';
```